# Using Slopes and Distances to Determine Quadrilaterals

Tags: quadrilateral, slope

Ok, so I recently came across this problem:

"Use slopes and distances to determine what kind of quadrilateral PQRS is created by each set of coordinate points.

1. $P(0,0), Q(0,2), R(5,5), S(2,0)$
2. $P(1,1), Q(5,1), R(4,8), S(2,8)$
3. $P(2,1), Q(7,1), R(7,7), S(2,5)$
4. $P(0,7), Q(4,8), R(5,2), S(1,1)$
5. $P(1,7), Q(5,9), R(8,3), S(4,1)$
6. $P(5,1), Q(9,6), R(5,11), S(1,6)$ "

I've tried all sorts of things involving slope and distance, but none are coming out or making any sense. Could some one please help me figure out what to do?

Comment: If you have tried, show us your work. Maybe we can point out the improvements needed. I don't think any one of us will spend time in finding all the possible slopes or distances for you.

Comment: @Mick Okay, I will try to get my work up! Also, I wasn't suggesting that you find the slopes/distances for me, but rather help me figure out what to do. . . It'll be up in a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

(0) Sketch the points to get an initial guess. For example, #1 could be a kite.

(1) For equal distances -- if two pair of opposite sides are equal in length, that figure is a parallelogram (at least).

(2) For slopes --

(a) If $m_1 \times m_2 = -1$, we have two perpendicular lines.

(b) If two adjacent angles have the same characteristics of (a), it probably is a rectangle.

(c) If $m_1 = m_2$, then the two lines are parallel...